# How to filter out empty cells in Google Sheets with Query & Importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am trying to use this formula but it's not working. Do you hava an idea why?

`QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("IMPORTEDDATASHEET";"06_20!M:AJ");"SELECT SUM(Col17) WHERE Col1 = 'Company Name' AND Col23 <> ' ' label SUM(Col17) ''")`

I want to filter by a specific company name in `Col1` and filter out all empty cells in `Col23` and then sum up `Col17`.

I also tried `IS NOT NULL` and `!= ' '` instead of `<> ' '`, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You have an aggregate — `SUM(Col17)` — which means you need to `GROUP BY` some column (e.g., add `GROUP BY Col1` to the `QUERY` before `LABEL`). If you don't tell the `QUERY` how to organize (i.e., `GROUP`) the aggregate function, it will throw an error.